# Android parsing xml does not work empty output

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse this xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<Items>
<Item>
    <DetailPageURL>
        https://www.amazon.de/Chemie-76128-Felgenreiniger-Alu-Teufel-Spezial/dp/B004LAXG9C?psc=1
        &SubscriptionId=myKey&tag=myTAG&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&
        creative=165953&creativeASIN=B004LAXG9C
    </DetailPageURL>
    <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/412-16OaNFL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
    <Feature>Der neue "Alu-Teufel-Spezial"" ist ein moderner Hochleistungs-Felgenreiniger. Die
        neue, säurefreie Rezeptur ermöglicht die problemlose Reinigung von Stahl- und
        Aluminiumfelgen sowie Radkappen.
    </Feature>
    <FormattedPrice>EUR 13,50</FormattedPrice>
    <Title>Tuga Chemie 76128 Felgenreiniger Alu-Teufel Spezial</Title>

</Item>
</Items>
```

I only want to have the `Feature` element to be shown in `TextView`

This is my code to parse the XML. I don't know why it does not work. If you run this program, there will be an empty output. So I guess something is wrong with my if condition.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();


            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean feature = false;


                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Feature")) {
                        feature = true;
                    }

                }//end of startElement method

                @Override
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                                       String qName) throws SAXException {
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    if (feature) {

                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n\n Feature : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        feature = false;
                    }

                }//end of characters
            };//end of DefaultHandler object

            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("test.xml");
            saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Try to debug, to see if you reach your various handler methods.

Comment: @Ridcully i did and I got into the catch part, so there is an IO Exception, but I don't know why.

Comment: what does the exception say?